# Linearlayout background image in assets folder

Tags: android, image, drawable, android-linearlayout, assets

I want to use a Image from the assets folder as my background image in android
but the only picture I can use is out oif the drawable folder

```
random = String.valueOf(util_random.random(1, 4));
        String drawable = "/assets/images/img"+random ;
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        this.setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not put that image on the `res/Drawable` folder?

Comment: yes the names are generated via random

Comment: Yes, but all those random names are already in the assets folder.. so there's no difference, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a String in [View.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

Use [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to create a Bitmap, then create a [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) and use it as your background image.

Comment: Also, when you have four images and you want to display one of them randomly, you can (and should) still put them in res/drawable.

Comment: when I use taht nothing happens

Comment: `int[] ids = { R.drawable.awesome1, R.drawable.awesome2, R.drawable.awesome3, R.drawable.awesome4 }; int pic = new Random().nextInt(ids.length); ll.setBackgroundResource(ids[pic]);`